# Which future form fits the context best - Future Simple or to be going to?

Tags: will-vs-going-to

Which tense is a better fit in the given context? If both, please give your arguments.

A: Now that he has learnt to kite surf, he ***will participate***/***is going to participate*** in a competition on Sunday.

B: That's exciting. I think I'll go to watch him.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the context.

"A" is assuming the intention of the subject, the one who has learnt to kite: then *to be going to* is the right choice.

"A" is giving their personal opinion "[I think] he will participate..." then *will* is the right choice.

Comment: This is the correct answer. But note that these scenarios overlap quite a bit, so most of the time, either choice will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Both are grammatically correct, but they're not the same, and one is better.

As usual, "be going to" is the standard future tense with no extra nuance, just a neutral statement describing a future event.

Using "will", however, carries the nuance that this is a *prediction*, rather than something known about the future, so it carries less confidence.

While it makes sense to predict he will begin to participate in competitions *in general*, or in *one particular competition*, it makes less sense to predict someone will participate in some competition *on a specific day*.

So, "*...participate in **a** competition on Sunday...*", sounds like something the speaker already knows, rather than a prediction, which makes "be going to" a better choice here.